# How to change Visual Studio's default xml encoding to "utf-16"

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

Is there any way to set *Visual Studio 2005/2008*'s default new `xml/xsl/xsd` files to be `utf-8` instead of `utf-16`?

I've done some looking but I just can't find a good site to refer to.. also I've looked all over the options but i don't see it...

Any clue?

Comment: That's odd. Mine defaults to utf-8

Comment: yea - it's a real problem for us as we use svn and a form of "svn spam" that diffs the files and sends us the diff via email.. only problem is the differ doesn't "do" utf16 so we get "binary files differ"...

Comment: we can 'remember' to switch to utf8 - but lots of times for new files we forget...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently this is impossible... :(

Answer (score 1):

Since you can’t set the default in the options, you may consider these alternatives:
http://devblog.ailon.org/devblog/post/2007/11/05/File-Encoding-in-Visual-Studio.aspx

The default encoding is based on the language Windows is set to. However, you may be able to change that. In Visual Studio, click Options > Environment > International Settings.
Set to “English” if you can. That’s what my VS is set to, and my new XML files default to utf-8.

Also, you can always change the encoding when you save a file, even though that’s not really the solution to your problem. Click File > Advanced Save Options, and select UTF-8.